# Проблемы создания папок под win/linux

Tags: java

Собственно программка сортирует мп3 файлы по тегам. Вот код, создающий папки

```
File file = new File(Path);
if (file.exists()) {
    try {
        f.save(Path + Name);
        System.out.println(i + "/" + col.size() + Name + " is Saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
} else {
    file.mkdirs();
    try {
        f.save(Path + Name);
        System.out.println(i + "/" + col.size() + Name + " is Saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

и путь задается как `Path = ".\\result\\" + Artist + "\\"+ Year+ "-" + Album + "\\";`
на винде все прекрасно работает, а на линуксе он создает файлы с жуткими именами

[image: Так выглядит в линуксе]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для большинства файловых систем обратный слеш не имеет специального смысла, и может присутствовать в имени файла. NTFS - одно из редких исключений. Даже Windows API понимает прямые слеши (и транслирует их в обратные).

Итак, пользуйтесь *только* прямыми слешами, и будет вам счастье. Кросс-платформенное.

PS: Java предоставляет File.separator (хотя кроме как в UI он нигде не нужен).